# python-shell history

Tags: python, shell

When I code in shell for practicing and when I am done I close it, when I reopen it I cannot code in it again I have to open a new one !

How can I code in the same old one of shell ??

Answer (score 2):

`python` command doesn't preserve your work

You can try installing [IPython](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable), Jupyter, or use a proper IDE for practicing

Answer (score 1):

The python shell isn't meant to write full programs. It's nice for testing small pieces of code, but if you'd like to continue previous code, use the Python IDLE that comes with the standard download installation (in python shell -> File -> New File). This will require you to save the file to run the code. However, this IDE is not very user friendly. As user cricket_007 has mentioned, there are other IDE's that have autocomplete and other helpful tools.

Answer (score 0):

Start using a terminal multiplexer like `tmux` or `screen` and launch python under it. My favourite is `tmux`. Your python session would persist till you kill the `tmux` session or till logout / reboot